What size LVL beam do I need to replace a load-bearing wall?
I’m in the process of removing a load bearing wall and hoping for a little help to spec a LVL beam.
I know I could run a triple 11.875” 2.0E LVL as one contractor already quote me on that and it seems overkill and hoping to minimize the beam height.
I’m wondering if a triple 9.5” 2.0E beam would be enough since this is mostly a floor edge beam.
13’ of it is supporting a bedroom above with no roof load and only overlaps with a small 3’ span in the foyer area as seen in the diagram.
The beams on the supported floor above are 2x8x16 which I sisterd up to reduce bounce etc.
The wall being removed is shown in blue and the walls above and below are in green. The direction of the joists are shown in red.
Below the wall is a 2x6 wall w/ strip footing and block wall on the other end so no concern there.
Total opening span will be 15'6" edge to edge.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.






Those LVL beams are engineered.  The company that makes them might help or you should have an engineer sign off.  We do not know your house enough to say if the smaller beam would be good enough, and for replacing a load bearing wall, you want experts, not someone that will not be standing under the load if it is not enough to hold up.
